# My python function will not return value

Tags: python, function, hash, return, hashtable

I have a user-defined function that takes table-size (m) as input. I implement an empty list (of pairs [key,count], essentially an array with two fields) of that size and use linear hashing to insert generated random numbers into the list. So say the first random number (k) is 20 and the length of the list (m) is 9, the hash function (h0 = k%m) will return 2 (as that is the remainder when 20 is divided by 9). If that cell is empty, I want to insert the key value(k) into the first field and 1 (count of probes) into the second field. If that cell is not empty, I want to increment the index using the hash function (h0 = (h0 + i)%m) until an empty cell is found and insert there. I want to return the resulting list. I have a return statement in my function and the documentation I've read says assigning a new value when I call the function and using a print statement should work. I'm using PyCharm community edition. Could my IDE be the problem? (Below is my code)

```
import random

def linear(m):

hTable = [[None, None] for j in range (m)]

for n in range (1100):
    k = random.randint(1,10000)

    for i in range(len(hTable)):
        for j in range(len(hTable[i])):
            h0 = k % m

            if hTable[h0] == [None,None]:
                hTable[h0][0] = k
                hTable[h0][1] = 1

            else:
                while hTable[h0] != [None, None]:
                    hTable[h0][1] += 1
                    h0 = (h0 + i)%m

                else:
                    hTable[h0][0] = k
                    hTable[h0][1] = 1

                    return hTable

                hash = linear(1223)
                print(hash)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention when I run the script, I do not get any return errors, but I also do not get my desired output. My only output is "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: Did you simply forget to *call* your function? Something like `linear(5)`.

Comment: You are performing a len function on an object of type None in the line: `for j in range(len(hTable[i])):`. Did you mean to setup hTable as a two-dimensional array instead? If you want hTable to be two-dimensional you can do: `hTable = [[None for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The call for the function is in the script above.

Comment: @BKovac Yes, I changed my list implementation to "hTable = [[[] for i in range(2)] for j in range (m)]".

Comment: The code as it is now will throw an error because you cannot add 1 to an empty list entry (`hTable[i][1] +=1` will fail). If you initiate your table with `[[None,None] for j in range (m)]` instead, the code will run fine - given that you actually **call** your function. E.g. `t = linear(3);
print t` will print something like `[[None, None], [8944, 1], [None, None]]`.

Comment: So I changed my code as someone did mention that it would've gone through one iteration and returned because I had the else statement running first. The script above is still not returning the variable "hash" I use to call the function. When I try to call the function from the Python Console (I comment out the call in the script above) using "from compare_hashing import *; hash = linear(21); print(hash)" it never finishes running and the active message says "code unreachable"

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [None,None]*2
[None, None, None, None]
```

In Python, multiplying a list extends the list, it doesn't make it multidimensional. You probably wanted something like `[[None, None] for i in range(m)`.

(I'm also not sure what your code is doing in general, as on the first iteration everything will `== [None, None]` and cause your `else` block to be executed - which has a return in it, and thus the returned array will consist of `hTable[h0] = [k, 1]` and every other element `[None, None]`...)

Also, `h0` will have the same value through every iteration (since it's calculated from values which aren't change)... and you probably want to `return hTable`, not `[hTable]`, since it's already a list.

Comment: When the record in the list is [None, None], the else statement inserts "k" in left field and "1" in right, as this position has been probed 1 time. As I said, it's a hash function for inserting values into an empty list. The function returns an index, k and count are inserted if the cells are empty, if not while loop uses hash to get new index. "k" changes every time a new rand. number is generated which is "for n in range (1100)" times. "return hTable" did not work either. I also changed my list implementation to "hTable = [[[] for i in range(2)] for j in range (m)]" so thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the indentation of my return statement. The following works:

```
import random

def linear(m):

    hTable = [[None, 0] for j in range (m)]

    nums = [random.randint(1,10001) for n in range(1100)]

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        h0 = nums[i] % m

        while hTable[h0] != [None, 0]:
            hTable[h0][1] += 1
            h0 = (h0 + 1)%m

        else:
            hTable[h0][0] = nums[i]
            hTable[h0][1] = 1

    count = sum(i[1] for i in hTable)
    print (count)

    return hTable

l = linear(1223)
print(l)
```